# Google Sheet Script to Insert new row after column C

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a script to automatically add a new row after column `C` on a daily basis. Below is my script:

```
function recordHistory() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
   var source = sheet.getRange("c4:U4");
   var values = source.getValues();

   sheet.insertRowBefore(4);
   sheet.getRange("c5:U5").setValues(values);
};
```

Column A in the "test" sheet is a range imported from another sheet. The code above adds a new row then copies the range `C-U` to row `5`.

But I what I want is to add a row from column `C` only.

Comment: I suggest please clarify your question (maybe give an example) because "add a row from column C only" is not clear at all.

Comment: It is not possible to add a dimension either before or after an orthogonal dimension

Answer (score 0):

however coz the requirement change i just copy over the the whole line with format instead of value

```
function addFirstRow() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var firstRow = 3;
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("daily");
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var range = sh.getRange("A4:U4");
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    sh.insertRowsAfter(3,1);
  newRange = sh.getRange("A4:U4");
    newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```